# Ipad/Iphone versions, 2 targets, 1 code base

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am currently working on a cocos2d game for iOS. Currently I am checking at runtime if it is an ipad or iphone running and adjusting coordinates et.c. for this.

But now I want two versions, one for iPad and one for iPod touch/iPhone. So I want two targets but still use the same codebase.

Currently I check for

```
UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

to determine if which device is used. But now I want to check which app/target is used. In case someone uses the iPhone version on the iPad, I do not want it to be adjusted for iPad (the iphone version cost less so should not adjusted for ipad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for the iPhone app target you set the target device family to just iPhone, `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` will always return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone, even when on an iPad.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to change your behavior in different targets whilst using exactly the same code base is to create a pre-processor definition and omit it in one of the targets or set it differently in each of the targets. Then your code can be compiled differently to alter its behaviour based on this definition (for example through conditional compilation if you use an `#ifdef` directive).

Comment: Thanks for you reply! It was hard to decide which answer to mark as correct as both solutions where applicable. However the above answer was more convenient at the time.

Comment: I am making a new app now, an Universal App for both iPad and iPhone, with two targets, one full version an one free version. In your answer you say "omit it in one of the targets". If I define a constant (kIsFullVersion = YES) in this file, include it in the fullVersion, wont I get a compile error in the free version? A solution would be to have two files, but they then would have need to have the same filename :S

Comment: You can use and #ifdef block in your code to check if the symbol is defined, so that you not only won't get a compile error but you'll be able to change the logic in the code according to whether it is defined in the target or not!